# How to scroll other views with recyclerView in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have layout having RecyclerView with 5 TextViews and NestedScrollView is a parent layout. So I need to scroll all 5 TextViews with RecycleView. As per current implementation only RecycleView is scrolling. Please tell me how do i achieve this? My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.evs.demo.layout.FixedScrollingViewBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/md_deep_orange_500"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No Records" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No Records" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No Records" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No Records" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No Records" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For proper scrolling you can change the layout manager you have set in coding for recycler view. I hope it helps.

```
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
};
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Another solution

try below codes:

```
  RecyclerView recycleView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lastest_product_list);
recycleView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

You can modify your layout

```
 <ScrollView>
 <LinearLayout> 
     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/lastest_product_list"
          android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
          android:isScrollContainer="false">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Newbie, I want to scroll textview with Recycler view, I am able to handle scroling between nestedscrollview and   recyclerview

Comment: You need to add textview as a different row in recycler view and then I think you will be able to get the desired result. [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)

Comment: i dont want to add textview in side RecyclerView

Comment: You have set the height of the textview to wrap_content with no lines mentioned Just add the lines to textview and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the height of your recycler view to "wrap_content" instead of "0dp". This will make the recycler view takes its own height and it scrolls seamlessly with the parent Nested Scroll View.

Answer (score -1):

You should add 5 `TextView` inside `Recyclerview`. And 5 TextView is another view type of `Recyclerview`. You can follow this article to add footer type to `Recyclerview`.

http://takeoffandroid.com/android-customview/header-and-footer-layout-for-recylerview/

Comment: I dont want to add Textview inside RecyclerView